# making a wide drop down with reactstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, dropdown, reactstrap

Im trying to make a wide drop down, to show a login form in it , and im trying reactstrap for it:

this is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

  return (
    <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
        </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

I wish the dropdown Menu would be like 500 px wide, how exactly can I do that? is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the bootstrap css for the dropdown-menu. 
Working [Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-morse-1pv2e)

Comment: thank you ! could you land me another hand maybe? the drop down is hidden behind some element, I tried giving it z-index in this class but it didn't work, maybe you know a solution?

Comment: You can try css visibility: visible property on your drop-down parent element. Or It will be good if you can put your code into the code sandbox and share the link.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use reactStrap class to do that, you can try the following css as

```
 .dropdown-menu {
   width: 500px;
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you mean to add a className to the dropdown menu component?

Comment: thanks it worked, but I have another problem that the dropdown is behind some element, z-index won't help, do you know a solution maybe?

Comment: can you make a sandbox snippet so I can help you out ?